# Sklearn and Pymesh import causes conflicts

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pymesh

I am working on processing 3D meshes using PyMesh. `pip install pymesh2` has build error. Hence I installed from another release from the official github [page](https://github.com/PyMesh/PyMesh/releases/tag/v0.3). I am using `pymesh2-0.3-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl`.
I installed scikit-learn using pip install. Both installed successfully in my system.
While importing them, I observed something strange.
While importing Pymesh and Sklearn. Pymesh imported correctly. Sklearn is not
[image]
While importing Sklearn and Pymesh. Sklearn imported correctly. Pymesh is not
[image]
Seems like these two packages are conflicting each other!
Can someone help me what is the issue and any possible resolution?

Comment: I am unable to replicate this error. Are you using a virtualenv or conda env? 
Maybe just try to uninstall and re-install the packages again?

Comment: Yes @MusHusKat I am using virtualenv with python 3.6. Can you tell me your steps of installation

Comment: I tried uninstall and re-installing the package. The issue still remains with me. I am working on remote server using ssh. I am not able to install packages in global environment hence I am using virtualenv

Comment: I used a conda environment and simply installed the two packages using pip and was able to import them without any error. May I suggest using conda if it is not too heavy?

Comment: @MusHusKat I set up the conda environment. I had one question though. How did you install pymesh?

Comment: I could install both packages nicely. Thank you for the response! @MusHusKat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I used conda instead of virtual env and pip installed the pymesh using the wheel file from the github. That worked well for me!

Comment: Great! Could you please upvote my comment(s) :p